# OpenCV and Qt VideoCapture does not open the correct camera on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv and Qt to create an application. Inside the application I am creating a small tool to record video. For this reason and not to block the main event thread I created a separate dialog that contains a recording thread. In this thread for starters I wanted to just see the camera output(I have not introduced the recording code yet). So I subclassed `QThread` and the `run()` function is the following:

```
void VideoRecordThread::run(){
    cv::VideoCapture capture;
    cv::Mat frame;
    QImage img;

    qDebug() << "Opening camera" << cameraIndex ;
    capture.open(cameraIndex);

    if(!capture.isOpened()){
        qDebug() << "Could not open camera" << cameraIndex;
        emit threadReturned();
        return;
    }

    while(!stopFlag){
        capture >> frame;
        qDebug() << "Frame Width = " << frame.cols << "Frame Height = " << frame.rows;
        if(frame.cols ==0 || frame.rows==0){
            qDebug() << "Invalid frame skipping";
            continue;
        }
        img = cvMatToQImage(frame); //Custom function
        emit imageCaptured(img);
    }
    capture.release();
    emit threadReturned(); //Custom signal
    qDebug() << "Thread returning";
}
```

this is supposed to work, but the problem is that when the thread starts, I get a new dialog "out of the blue" asking me to select the camera when I select one of the cameras connected, it sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't. Here is the dialog that I get:

[image]

Any help on what can I do?

Comment: What value is `cameraIndex` ?

Comment: If there is only one camera or it does not matter what camera is used -1 may be passed. On Windows, index 0 opens that dialog for the user to select the video source.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed that OpenCV has problems when some functions are not executed from the main thread.

Move the initialization of the capture procedure to the main thread of your application and leave the rest on your secondary thread. The initialization part seems to be:

```
cv::VideoCapture capture;

qDebug() << "Opening camera" << cameraIndex ;
capture.open(cameraIndex);

if(!capture.isOpened())
{
    qDebug() << "Could not open camera" << cameraIndex;
    emit threadReturned();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that i got a mainwindow -> recodingdialog ->videorecording thread. How can i move the VideoCapture from thread 2 levels up to the mainwindow?

Comment: Just pass the `cv::VideoCapture` object across classes. You can put in the constructor of the classes if you want, so when a new class is initialized it already has access to the capture interface, or add a new method to set this variable in these classes after it was successfully initialized in the main thread. Or, as a last (ugly) option, declare `cv::VideoCapture capture` as a global variable -- I guess for testing purposes it would be faster to implement and test.