# Is it possible to use opencv functions from inside of a QThread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt, opencv

I intend to write a Qt GUI application which does a lot of image processing. To not freeze the display, I intend to put the calculations to a `QThread`, as some calculations can be in the range of a few seconds.

I managed to integrate Qt and opencv 2.31, and I successfully run some tests from the main (GUI) thread: creating images, drawing on them, performing basic algorithms, and displaying them in a `cvNamedWindow`. All works fine.

However, if I start a `QThread` and move my previous tests there, strange things happen:

- Allocating images or opening them from files, drawing on them (e.g. `cvLine`) works fine (I can send them to the GUI thread and display them)
- **performing most of the transformations crashes the application** (e.g. `cvSmooth`)
- using displaying functions (e.g. `cvNamedWindow`, `cvShowImage`) don't work, but at least they don't cause the program to crash, only sending "QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread" to the Qt debug output. (This one I understand, as cvNamedWindow is implemented in Qt and Qt only allows display from the main GUI thread)

Is there a way to use the image processing functions from a thread other than the main? It would be counter-intuitive to do edge detection etc. in the main thread, much less segmentation or other, resource-heavy algorithms ...

<sub>Here is an example which works in the main (GUI) thread but does not work in a QThread. This is using only the C API, because the C++ API gave me even more problems under Qt. This means a C solution will also be enough, but I'm open to other solutions using the C++ API.</sub>

```
IplImage *test;
test = cvCreateImage( cvSize(640,480), 8, 1 );
cvLine(test,cvPoint(20,20),cvPoint(100,100),cvScalar(255,0,0),3);  // works fine even in thread
cvSmooth( test, test, CV_GAUSSIAN, 11, 11 );                       // crashes if in thread
cvNamedWindow("test");                                             // warning if in thread
cvShowImage("test",test);                                          // warning if in thread
```

Answer (score 2):

[It is possible](http://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/), but OpenCV was not built to support calls from different threads. So you will need to use [mutexes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmutex.html) in your code.

Like you, I've [experienced problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10343890/176769) trying to accomplish this. You might want to move the code that draws the GUI to the 2nd thread, and leave the main thread reserved for the OpenCV calls, frame grabbing and all that stuff.

Comment: Strangely, the linked project uses the main thread for GUI and another thread for opencv, with mutexes. For me it still does not work. Just locking the example I provided in the question with a mutex does not change its behavior.

Comment: By the way, why should mutexes help in this situation? They only help in situation where the same code can be called from multiple threads. This is not the situation here.